# What is the point of Trivia Crack levels?

Tags: trivia-crack

I see that with time I move up levels as I play games. But there is hardly any documentation that shows what happens when I move up levels? Do the questions get tough? So if I play with a friend whose level is much lower than mine does that mean I get different difficulty level questions than him?

Comment: It is essentially a quick way to see how many correct questions a person has answered, I'd imagine. It has no practical effect on the game itself, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hmmm but I see that my questions are getting really tough as my levels increase

Comment: I kind of notice that, too. All my percentages are dropping. But that could just be due to a few factors. 1. All the easy questions appear at lower levels, so the harder ones remain at higher levels. This is to entice new users to stick around because the game is "easy". 2. When you encounter tough questions at low levels, you use coins to make them easier. Early on, coins are easy to get, mostly from achievements. 3. Personally, I get lazier the more I play and so give less though to my answers, so perhaps I'm subconsciously sabotaging my own score.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on level 220 and have answered over 25,000 questions correctly but I've been noticing that my questions have become more difficult and I'm getting beat by players with few games and lower percentages than me. So It appears the answer is yes. Higher level, harder questions.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that they get harder as there is no means to rate a question's difficulty in the Question Factory. I'm on level 110 and I still get ridiculously easy questions all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on level 334 and can guarantee you the questions definitely get much more difficult. They become much more exact. For example, "What jersey number did Don Drysdale wear in the 1968 World Series?" (Not a real question, but just a similar one). No more general questions like, "How many players on a baseball field during a game?" At this level it's very difficult to win many games (at least for me).

Answer (score -1):

I notice the questions are definitely harder as you go up but I believe they are at the level of the lower player. If I play a higher level player (then we are both higher) the questions are much harder.

Answer (score -1):

I really think the questions are random throughout the levels and don't get any harder.  In my friends group, in fact, the percentage of questions answered correctly has gone up throughout as people learn the gist of the game and how to use power-ups. It seems like the most difficult thing is that I rarely go up against people with losing records anymore, and it's uncommon whenever somebody quits in the middle of a game. At lower levels, there's plenty of that.

I do think people are matched up based upon the percentage of questions they answer correctly. A friend of mine is roughly 150-75 and she's in the 60s in every category except entertainment.  That's one thing I find pretty hard to explain.

Answer (score -1):

It is nothing like that. The questions are random and it has nothing to do with level. You have to the answer number of questions your next level is. For example my level is 166 I have to answer 167 questions to move to the next level. And like this one question keeps on increasing as you move level by level

Answer (score -1):

At level 336, I can guarantee you the questions become more difficult. I used to beat most players when I was under level 300, but now I lose most games. To those who think they don't get harder, you'll see once you get past level 300.